# How to create Guest Wishlist For Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php, wishlist

In Magento, the default functionality is that the customer click a wishlist link on any product when that customer is not logged in, then it redirects to login page and then the product has been stored in wishlist and shows in wishlist page after logged in. But according to requirement, I need the wishlist functionality for non logged in Customer also. The non logged in customer is capable to click a wishlist link and save and see the wishlist without logged in. That mean I think guest wishlist for magento. If any one knows about it. Please reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

1. Overwrite controller

Please copy file **app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php** to **app/code/local/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php**

Change property

```
protected $_skipAuthentication = true;
```

2. Alter table: **wishlist**

   - Remove **Unique** of column **customer_id**
   - Remove **Foreign Key** of column **customer_id**
   - Add column **cookie** type varchar(255)
3. Overwrite model **Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist**

   ```
   public function loadByCookie($ss, $create = false)
   {       
       $this->_getResource()->load($this, $ss, "cookie");

   if (!$this->getId() && $create) {
       $this->setCustomerId(0);
       $this->setCookie($ss);
       $this->setSharingCode($this->_getSharingRandomCode());
       $this->save();
   }

   return $this;        


   }
   ```

You can use ajax or merge wishlist after login at extension http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/customer-experience/guest-wishlist-use-ajax-for-magento.html

Answer (score -2):

**Without customization/ use extension,you cannot do it.**

for extension,you can use

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/guest-wishlist-for-magento.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/guest-wishlist.html

As customization,can use

[Add to wishlist without customer login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32635/add-to-wishlist-without-customer-login)

Comment: First two are paid extension, second one is not proper solution. I need more information for creating this extension or free extension. Client don't want to buy the paid extension. If you know  more thing about this above feature, please reply me as soon as possible. Thank you.